# Application with identifier <team-id.com.example.bundle-id> is not associated with domain <www.example-domain.com>

Tags: ios, swift, fido, associated-domains

I'm developing a native library for iOS which is ment to be used for Single Sign On.
I need to share credentials with a backend service, for which I followed this steps: (According to FIDO2 standard and [this example](https://github.com/teamhanko/apple-wwdc21-ios-demo-shiny))

#### 1. I enabled Associated Domains in my application

[image]

#### 2. Backend service hosted the /.well-known/apple-app-site-assiciation.json

```
{
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "<TEAM-ID>.<com.example.bundle-id>"
    ]
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1004 "Application with identifier P896AB2AMC.com.trust.testsso is not associated with domain cerberus.trust.lat" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application with identifier P896AB2AMC.com.trust.testsso is not associated with domain cerberus.trust.lat}
error in connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted
```

I don't know exactly what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got the site-association a bit wrong. The correct URL is `https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` - you are using `...apple-app-site-association.json`. Strip off the `.json` at the end, then you should be good to go.

For a full explanation see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: Thank you very much, It was exactly what was causing troubles.